# RubyMotion + Pebble SDK for iOS

Tags: rubymotion, pebble-sdk

Trying to call `appMessagesLaunch` from the Pebble iOS SDK (statically linked) with RubyMotion causes the following error:

```
Objective-C stub for message appMessagesLaunch: type v@:@? not precompiled. Make sure you properly link with the framework or library that defines this message.
```

It seems the RubyMotion generated BridgeSupport file (`vendor/Pebble/PebbleKit.framework/build-iPhoneOS/PebbleKit.framework.bridgesupport`) does not contain a definition for `appMessagesLaunch`.

Any ideas?

Using RubyMotion version 3.6
Pebble iOS SDK cloned from https://github.com/pebble/pebble-ios-sdk/

See https://github.com/lshepstone/motion-pebble for a code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by adding the following two lines to the PBPebbleCentral.h file, just after the `#import`.

```
@interface PBWatch : NSObject
@interface PBWatch (AppMessages)
```